# Angular: Some routes use PathLocationStrategy but some other routes use HashLocationStrategy

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular-routing, angular-router

I have 4 routes in my app.routes.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

export const pageRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'transaction', loadChildren: './app/transaction.module#TransactionModule'},
  {path: 'evidence', loadChildren: './app/evidence.module#EvidenceModule'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(pageRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

In the app.routes, I didn't do any specific setup for `LocationStrategy`. Since for the `transaction` route, I want to use the angular2 default PathLocationStrategy, which doesn't allow the user to refresh the page.

But for the `evidence` route, I actually want the users to be able to refresh the page. So I'd like to use HashLocationStrategy here.

This is the `evidence-routing.module`

```
    @NgModule({

          imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
            {path:':sessionId', component: EvidenceComponent}
            { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' },
            { path: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
          ])], 
          exports: [RouterModule],
          providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]

    })
    export class EvidenceRoutingModule {}
```

I wanted to add `providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }]` inside `evidence-routing.module` to enable HashLocationStrategy and only apply to this route.

But once I put it there, the entire application will adopt the HashLocationStrategy, it also works for the transaction route.

I couldn't find any good solutions to handle this.

Any advice on this issue?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a different `LocationStrategy` for different routes, this setting is for the `Router`, not for routes, and there can only be exactly one router for one application.

You should rather ensure the server is configured properly, then reload will work for all routes even with `PathLocationStrategy`.

Ensure your server is configured to support HTML5 pushState.
This just means that the server returns `index.html` for requests to unknown resources.